# Python MRJob Script Sorting Results - Top Ten Words Syllable Count

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am trying to make a job that takes in a text file, only processes words that are not in the STOPWORDS set, counts the number of syllables in each word, then returns the top 10 words with the most syllables, sorting the results.

I believe everything is correct, I just am not sure how to make the reducer sort the results.

Here is my code:

```
%%file top_10_syllable_count.py

import re
from sys import stderr
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[\w']+")

import syllables

def splitter(text):
    WORD_RE = re.compile(r"[\w']+")
    return WORD_RE.findall(text)


def sort_results(results):
    """
    Sorts a list of 2-tuples descending by the first value in the 
    tuple, ascending by the second value in the tuple.
    """
    return sorted(results, key=lambda k: (-k[0], k[1]))


STOPWORDS = {
    'i', 'we', 'ourselves', 'hers', 'between', 'yourself', 'but', 'again', 'there', 'about', 'once', 'during',
    'out', 'very', 'having', 'with', 'they', 'own', 'an', 'be', 'some', 'for', 'do', 'its', 'yours', 'such',
    'into', 'of', 'most', 'itself', 'other', 'off', 'is', 's', 'am', 'or', 'who', 'as', 'from', 'him', 'each',
    'the', 'themselves', 'until', 'below', 'are', 'we', 'these', 'your', 'his', 'through', 'don', 'nor', 'me',
    'were', 'her', 'more', 'himself', 'this', 'down', 'should', 'our', 'their', 'while', 'above', 'both', 'up',
    'to', 'ours', 'had', 'she', 'all', 'no', 'when', 'at', 'any', 'before', 'them', 'same', 'and', 'been',
    'have', 'in', 'will', 'on', 'does', 'yourselves', 'then', 'that', 'because', 'what', 'over', 'why', 'so',
    'can', 'did', 'not', 'now', 'under', 'he', 'you', 'herself', 'has', 'just', 'where', 'too', 'only', 'myself',
    'which', 'those', 'i', 'after', 'few', 'whom', 't', 'being', 'if', 'theirs', 'my', 'against', 'a', 'by',
    'doing', 'it', 'how', 'further', 'was', 'here', 'than'
}


class MRMostTenSyllables(MRJob):
    def steps(self):
        return[
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_words),
            MRStep(reducer=self.reducer_find_max_word)
        ]
    
    def mapper_get_words(self, _, line):
        for word in WORD_RE.findall(line):
            if word.lower() not in STOPWORDS:
                syllable_count = syllables.estimate(word)
                yield None, (syllable_count, word.lower())
                
    def reducer_find_max_word(self, key, values):
        self.list = []
        for value in values:
            self.list.append(value)
            self.new = []
        for i in range(10):
            self.new.append(max(self.list))
            self.list.remove(max(self.list))
        for i in range(10):
            yield self.new[i]
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    start = time.time()
    MRMostTenSyllables.run()
    end = time.time()
    debug("Run time:", end - start, "seconds")
```

Comment: Sort results by what? Each key goes to a different reducer, so you currently cannot sort by syllables

Comment: I want to sort results by def sort_results(results):
    """
    Sorts a list of 2-tuples descending by the first value in the 
    tuple, ascending by the second value in the tuple.
    """
    return sorted(results, key=lambda k: (-k[0], k[1]))

Comment: I don't think that function does what you want unless you're trying to sort the values by word length tuples, for example

Comment: I updated my code.  Right now it is returning a list of tuples, but both tuples are sorted by descending order.  I want the second tuple to be sorted by ascending order.

Comment: Example output: 6 "unimaginable"
6 "revolutionized"
6 "plenipotentiaries"
6 "phonotelephote"
5 "unfortunately"
5 "undiscovered"
5 "temperature"
5 "specifically"
5 "overpowering"
5 "originated"
Output I want: 6 "phonotelephote"
6 "plenipotentiaries"
6 "revolutionized"
6 "unfortunately"
6 "unimaginable"
5 "accumulator"
5 "accumulators"
5 "agriculture"
5 "civilization"
5 "communicate"

Comment: I don't understand the difference between those outputs. The sixes are shown before the fives. Are you asking how to alphabetically sort as well? Your code isn't currently doing that, only by syllable count

Comment: Yes, I want the tuples to be sorted highest to lowest by number and then sorted alphabetically (a-z).  Right now it is sorting z-a